# Reset driver session quits the automation test when running on BrowserStack

Tags: java, selenium, browserstack

When running my automation test across to platforms there is a login conflict, I resolved this conflict by creating a method that resets the browser session before switching between the two platforms:

```
public RemoteWebDriver resetDriverSession() {
    if (this.driver != null) {
        this.driver.quit();
    }
    return getInstance();
}
```

This works locally but when running on BrowserStack this method quits the session.
I have also created a method that uses the Chrome UI (Version 86.0.4240.111) to clear the history

```
        case CLEAR_CACHE:{
            RemoteWebDriver driver = driverFactory.getInstance();
            driver.manage().deleteAllCookies();
            driver.get("chrome://settings/clearBrowserData");
            driver.switchTo().activeElement();
            driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("* /deep/ #clearBrowsingDataConfirm")).click();
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"clearBrowsingDataConfirm\"]")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//settings-ui")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
            break;
        }
    }
```

This method opens the chrome history settings but it does not click the Clear data button. Please can someone advise what is wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I think BrowserStack will always terminate the session whenever the driver.quit(); will be executed. You might want to try other methods/alternatives to achieve the same use case.